# Why does Hollywood not use foreigners in foreigners' roles?

Tags: character, casting

This is a question that bothers me for a really long time. For example, Russians in every (not literally, but you get the point) Hollywood movies/TVshows are acted by English-speaking actors. It is really annoying to see the roles where “fluent” or “native” speaker twists a foreign language. It is embarrassing.

I'd like to know, is there any reason, why Hollywood does not use native speakers. I'll bet there are tons of different language speaker actors around LA, but still, in production, we hear ridiculous goo. And I don't whine about main roles, I can forgive Julia Roberts or George Clooney if they have a line or two in Mandarin. But, when there is a tiny part of the picture with 4 Armenian mobsters, why they could not be real Armenian actors, so it feels right in the details?

Is there any reason not to use native speaker actors?

I am from Estonia, it is a really small country (about 1.3 mln people), but even Estonian actors are available in LA, and I am pretty sure, they are not more expensive while more than good professionally for those small roles, which rarely pop up. So why Hollywood still use Serbians who never spoke Serbian?

Or Russians? There are hordes of them in LA, certainly. Why not pick them in Russian roles?

I admit, French, Italian and Spanish have much better coverage, but even German is frequently the rubbish.

Even when the writer is made a good job for background details it goes downhill (in this aspect) after casting...

There must be a rational reason for the situation. Maybe it's about trade unions?

**Edit on starting bounty**

I have read the answers below for some days now, and I must admit: I am not convinced. I think it is good to start a bounty to call more opinions to reveal more possibilities.

Most important, I state: for me, this question is about authenticity, I want to believe the story told on the screen. Bad use of language is a real turnoff, for me. Like there is [a lot of people](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/75487/82730), who find disturbing when certain dialect of English is not accurate.

I analyze some hypotheses so far, to show, why I can't accept those as an Answer.

**Reason 1**: it is very hard to find foreigner actors in Hollywood

Hollywood is soon a century a place that sucks young actors around to globe into. For now, there should be them in any nation and any age, both men and women. Certainly not any combination of any, but still. There is no other place like this on Earth, to my knowledge.

Same time European small studios use most times native speakers in corresponding roles, whenever and as close as possible. As from @AryanSonwatikar comment, seems Bollywood acts the same way.

**Reason 2**: budget does not allow

Hollywood shows have budgets in the industry no comparable with anything else.

1. If we think a bit how much is contributed to visual integrity and right shooting places, for example, and how much things are developed in this area during 50-60 years, this is been all in the name of being more believable. Compared with all those expenses seems argumenting with a budget in native speaking actors topic somehow hard to grasp. Are they more expensive in small roles?
2. Would be filling small roles with unknown actors more expensive than using known actors as fake natives? Rather not, I think. Of course, unknown adds risks, so from this aspect there are downsides. Including rookies (or different work ethics or culture) has always its benefits and worries. Still, it seems more about the next reason:

**Reason 3**: being risk-averse

This seems so far most convincing. Still, it is risky to belittle your audience, too. Or?

Here belong also networking: using people who you already know or are in certain circles already. Use them, they have already proved themself...

**Reason 4**: actors box office value

Unless we talking about leading actors or supporting actors, this seems not relevant to me.

**Reason 5**: casting (and actually nobody) does not understand it anyway and can't tell how authentic it was (speaking some native language)

This is a tricky one. I want to apologize already for everyone who finds following somehow insulting. But this is really hard to understand to me.

I try to explain it from my perspective (it is certainly not one-to-one with everyone, but still I found it pretty common here, where I live). If I hear somewhere in the World some (not known to me) Estonian to speak whatever another language I almost always can point out that the speaker is Estonian. Takes years and years every day speaking to mask your mother tongue, to get it sound really fluent (depends also from the person and how close is language to yours). And, for some degree I can use the same method for some shortlist of other languages, I have more experience.

Now, following my own (but common here) experience it is hard to understand, how casting managers can't make a difference between being fluent or being English trying to fake? I understand that on casting is almost impossible to tell, does actor really speak Latvian or maybe Lithuanian, but for attentive listener should be not too hard to detect your mother tongue in the speaker's "native" language. Or?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110516/discussion-on-question-by-w-k-why-does-hollywood-not-use-foreigners-in-foreigner).

Comment: Since you have rejected all the answers - several of which appear to be quite correct - you seem to have an agenda hidden in your question and want only a particular answer, which satisfies your agenda. What answer are you looking for?

Comment: @Gramps I don't know the workflow of producing movies/TV shows. So I was truly seeking for answer from insight. I have a hypothesis: casting for small roles goes through the agencies. The agency wants to push its actors. If they have an Albanian actor, they push him/her for a Russian role. They may ask from Albanian: are you ready for a Russian role? And of course, he/she is, because of the paycheck. And because he/she knows: Swedish, Latvian and Bulgarian are in the line, being maybe worse. So, it may be a convenience: we use some agency for subcasting and don't care too much for authenticity

Comment: I think your hypothesis is covered in the answers - perhaps not everything in one answer, but the gist of your hypothesis  is included in the answers.

Comment: @Gramps I agree. I also have other hypotheses, but I don't want to confirm my hypothesis. I'd like to get a viable and truthful answer. Of course, this type of question can't get one and only straight answer, but it has to have some sense in it, which describes the inner mechanics how production works.

Answer (score 44):

This is not entirely the case from what I have seen. More frequently, a specific type of character (Russian, for instance) is played over and over again by the same, small, group of actors well known in the entertainment community. The same Russians get the same Russian parts. The same Italians get the same Italian parts.

If the part is too small to bother, or the actor sought is not available, studios don’t bother trying to develop new talent for a one shot deal. They would rather go with someone who can get close to acting the part. And, they will count on the audience suspending their belief for the sake of the storyline. The belief being that it is better entertainment to have good acting than realistic portrayal. Especially when the portrayal of the character must be exaggerated for the audience to get what would normally be subtleties.

Case in point, I like action movies. Combat movies are shot predominantly with actors who have never been trained in combat. Instead, they go through a crash course on combat techniques. Then, their scenes are choreographed for the maximum visual effect. The audience impact is valued over the actual realism. Even if it means that certain effective combat techniques are replaced with those that would go against actual training, be ill-advised, or be down-right disastrous  in actual combat. When actual combat veterans are cast in speaking roles, the realism of combat scenes increases. But, the acting and dialogue quality suffers. It is not in the combat veterans’ skill set. Can it be taught/learned? Yes, at the expense of time. But, it is much easier to teach an actor how to act like the character at the expense of realism.

Comment: It is not pro vs acting. I don't miss linguists play foreigners, I miss actors who possess one important part for a specific character: language. I am a programmer and most aspects of this arealso rubbish, I can overlook them mostly, where they are not relevant. If a story is about a certain national character, it seems important enough. Why bring in diversity when you can't carry it out? You could not accept the movie, where instead of the actual jungle are just decorations. If it could be about money, then of course. But I can't see using native speaker actors being more expensive. Or?

Comment: My example of combat was an analogy. It was analogous to the skill or character trait of language and/or culture. The goal of the finished product of films other than documentaries is to entertain. Some suspense of belief and use of imagination is necessary. Since time is money, if it is quicker to find someone who can act rather than a native of a specific culture who might act, then that is significant. Especially if casting a good actor makes a better finished product. The same issue has happened in history with female roles played by males, or ethnic roles played by other ethnicities.

Comment: In action, you need to find compromise between being able to fight as a pro and being able to act like a pro. (And there are lots of tools in makers bag, to make action **visually** appealing) Following this analogy, we should seek midway between language professor and pro actor. But this is not the case. And makers have almost no tools to fake speaking foreign language, actors are pretty naked with their heavy accent. Language (speaking) is a large part of actors personal charisma (think for example of  Penelope Cruz), even if they fight better than speak (Arnold Schwarzenegger).

Comment: Just to give an example: Popular Russian Actor in TV: Konstantin "Costa" Ronin has had a few good parts the last few years from Agent Carter, The Americans, and Homeland. He is Russian born, but is in fact labeled a "New Zealand" actor (and cinematographer).

German Actor:  Daniel Bruhl has played quite a few German characters (or of German decent) from The Zookeeper's Wife, Cloverfield Paradox, The Alienist, and Captain America (franchise). But he is also of Spanish decent and has played Spaniards too like in Spanish Buisnessman.

Comment: One name immediately comes to mind is [**Andrew Howard**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Howard). He lately plays Russians or East Europeans almost exclusively. I was shocked to know he's actually Welch.

Comment: The typical Hollywood Russian is usually the one who looks like a bandit or a drunk, speaks Russian with a horrible accent, and can't even pronounce common names correctly - that's most of my personal experience at least. The best I can remember is Mission Impossible 4, but even there there's Ethan Hunt's prison mate.

Comment: @DarthLocke: and Vincent Cassel (Ocean's 12 and 13, Black Swan, Westworld) is the go-to French bad guys.

Comment: If you look at kung fu-flicks of the 60-80's, you'll likely see a bunch of martial artists hired to play the parts. These are classic movies because of the martial arts prowess, but the acting sucks. They used one type of expert to the disadvantage of other parts of the film. Hugh Laurie, well known for his part in the TV series "House", has a British accent, but he suppressed it for the role as an American. He isn't a doctor, yet he pulled that off, too, even though a real doctor or nurse would likely groan at what he does. Realism is what coaches, choreographers, FX, and consultants are for.

Comment: @computercarguy - I agree. It’s all about the story. And, the story is all about driving emotion. As a pilot, I would go out of my way to listen to Sullenberger & Skiles talk about the facts of their flight. As a consumer of entertainment (which most people are), I prefer the way Hanks & Eckhart brought the story to life for entertainment value. People will remember the way actors & their stories made them feel before they remember if the actor said it 100° correctly. Even Laurie did not nail his “American” accent. He sounded like a Brit living in the U.S.. I still liked his show.

Comment: @DeanF., yep. The Neo and Morpheus "I know kung fu" fight scene is pretty bad, but that's a small part of the movie, so it didn't really matter that they moved like white belts, even as they were supposed to be masters. Sames goes for other medical shows. House showed "extreme diagnosis", Grey's Anat shows "excellence", and other medical shows focusing on other aspects, with Scrubs apparently being the most medically accurate, since they focus on humor not medicine. It's really about the story and what the focus of the show/movie is rather than the actors/actresses skills in that discipline.

Comment: @computercarguy - Yes, the story, and the emotional impact from the telling of it, are the most important aspect of a movie or show. Would the value (artistic or monetary) of “Sully” be better if the actors were pilots? Even if those actors were Harrison Ford, Kurt Russell, Tom Cruise, Morgan Freeman, Dennis Quaid, John Travolta, Hilary Swank or Clint Eastwood (who directed the film). Admittedly, Brad Pitt & Angelina Jolie would have added a different chemistryto the movie. And, Chuck Norris realistically looks and sounds like Sully. He wouldn’t even get wet. The Hudson would get Chuck Norris.

Comment: @DeanF., "The Hudson would get Chuck Norris." Brilliant! +1

Comment: @w.k The problem seems to be in that you view this as "bringing in diversity" instead of "making a good movie". Most people simply don't care about this kind of stuff.

Comment: @user91988 Sorry, but I don't write scripts where foreigner dudes make their things. I am not involved bringing in diversity. Neither am I demanding it. I just see that it is made pretty poorly. For me is acceptable solution do not involve foreigners if those are not actually important of the point of the show...

Comment: @w.k Okay, but we're not talking about your scripts. Your personal opinion is not relevant.

Comment: @DeanF. "People will remember the way actors & their stories made them feel before they remember if the actor said it 100° correctly." - sigh, it's (probably accurate) statements like this one that make me feel utterly disconnected from much of humanity :/

Answer (score 25):

I see this has three bases…

1. Budget
2. Actor's box-office value
3. Whether or not casting can tell the difference. This is a big one!

Let me take a slightly different perspective, as I work in London not Hollywood.

Non-British actors playing "British" for staters.
You've all heard Mel Gibson playing Scots, or Dick van Dyke playing a Cockney. These are just the tip of the iceberg. Across the years, the number of Americans with simply abysmal British accents is heart-breaking.

I can hear minor aberrations in British accents like you can tell the difference between Estonian and Serbian. I can't. Most people outside those areas couldn't, so they all get through on Reason 3.

Even British actors playing British parts don't always get it right - Game of Thrones… a whole slew of dodgy "Northern" accents, enough to make you wince. Some were spot on, Sean Bean and Mark Addy set the bar, as true native Northerners, Sheffield to be precise. Richard Madden - a Scotsman - did a really good job of copying them. After that it all went a bit downhill. Neither casting nor 90% of the show's audience would be able to tell that a great percentage of the rest of the 'Northern' cast only managed "something that might be somewhere near Manchester if you're not listening too carefully".
They also got through on Reason 3.

Anyway, back to Americans playing Brits - and vice versa.
Over recent years, many actors have spent considerable effort brushing up on their accents. Compare Hugh Laurie in House Season 1 vs Season 8. To start with I don't know what accent he was trying to do. By the end, I'd say he'd pretty much nailed it.
Another I've worked with - Elle Fanning. In Maleficent… not so good. In The Great, nailed it.
Some are so good that once you've checked where they were born on IMDB, you still wonder how they did it. Such as Meryl Streep and Christian Bale fit this category.

If casting want a certain character actor, then the job has traditionally gone to the best actor for the part, not necessarily the best accent copyist. This is, fortunately changing, but because the actors are taking the time to actually get the accents right. The entire industry is becoming much more aware of this in recent years. I've worked on shows where to play a Russian, you have to **be** a Russian, German to play a German, etc. I've also played parts myself as a German, in German - but on that occasion the script supervisor was so bi-lingual it was impossible to tell which was her native language. She made certain no-one got it wrong. If anyone's accent slipped, we'd be going again.

So - there is hope on the horizon.

Comment: I thought Renée Zellweger did a good accent job for Bridget Jones.

Comment: What accent did Laurie nail by the end of House season 8? Brit accent? Isn't he Brit?

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire - "American". Gregory House is American, Hugh Laurie is British.

Comment: For a really bad "Brit doing a British accent" I refer you to Daphne Moon's "Manchester" accent in Frasier. Sounds like she didn't even bother trying.

Comment: I'll give her a "Game of Thrones" of 7. She is actually a Brit, but not a northerner. I always thought she generally got it pointing in the right direction, but it wasn't perfect by a long way. I often thought it was over-cooked on purpose. Her screen brother, Simon,  though… ye gods, that was van Dyke territory :\ [Otherwise her brothers were mostly played by brits]

Comment: On Hugh Laurie, I was completely put off of House because it sounded to me like the accent he used to do in A Bit of Fry and Laurie when they were making fun of Americans.

Comment: *Game of Thrones* does not take place in Britain, or even on Earth.  It may be inspired by British lore, but it isn't Britain.  The people of the fictional fantasy realm of Westeros can sound like whatever the show-runners decide they want them to sound like.  Thus there is no such thing as a "wrong" accent for that show.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - yeah, sure. We know. That doesn't make it any less irritating that they didn't in fact pay sufficient attention to the accents for people who actually know what they are. Normally, people from a single area speak with the same accent… they didn't even get a single family to speak with the same accent. They did studiously avoid having anyone with a Scots accent to avoid "the wall" being any more linked to Hadrian's & tended to use Scandi accents for North of it. That shows there was **some** thought went into it… just not enough.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman another (worse) example of what Tetsujin is talking about (the inconsistent accent of an imaginary people) is found in the recent *Wonder Woman* movie.  Someone decided that the Themyscirans should all try to speak with an Israeli accent (like Gal Gadot), but the non-Israelis actors do a terrible job.  No two actors have the same accent, and worse, the (non-Israeli) actors can't maintain a consistent accent, flailing around in a Russian-Arabic-British muddle. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGK7hJGjJQI

Comment: ll to the GOT accent point, while it might of been nicer to be a better parallel in being an equivalent to historically or realistically accurate, I think that personality and how lines are delivered actually matter more to this medium. What good is it if everyone sounds accurate, but no one acts well or every characters lines from all the northerners are NOT very distinguishable from any other? How does that necessarily help the characterization, themes, or pure enjoyment of the story?

Comment: @Juhasz A parallel I would've drawn would be to the *Black Panther* movie.  Everybody in Wakanda has genuine African accents in the movie (they are mostly native African actors), but they're all from *different parts* of Africa.  In this case it was a deliberate choice as they wanted to represent the whole continent even though it takes place in one small fictional country.  I imagine it might be slightly jarring to African audiences to hear so many wildly different accents spoken in one location.

Comment: As an interesting counterpoint to GOT: although The Lord Of The Rings is ostensibly set in Europe from ages past, it's effectively a world of its own — yet the movies not only used UK accents, but ones from a variety of regions and classes, all carefully chosen to match the characters. And all were performed well; many were impeccable, even from Americans or Australians. If only more movies cared that much about accent!

Answer (score 20):

Great answers here, but an issue I don’t see highlighted as much as I think it deserves is that

#### Hollywood is extremely risk-averse.

Feature films have enormous budgets, and turning those budgets into successful films that actually make a profit is a difficult task. As budgets increase, the difficulty of recouping the expenditures increases in turn. And we have seen a lot of extremely-high-budget films. Anything that can lower the difficulty—increase the odds of success—is prized highly by the people with the money, who are the people that are really in charge.

What this means is that Hollywood is fairly well obsessed with minimizing risk. That means you want the most established, famous, likely-to-draw-more-crowds actor you can afford for every role. The more minor the role, the less budget you have to fill it—a big famous star in a leading role can draw huge crowds just by slapping their name on the film, so Hollywood is willing to spend a lot of money on that role. The same actor can’t draw the same crowds in some more minor role, so they aren’t worth hiring for that role—that role must be filled more cheaply. The more minor the role, the less money the studio can spend filling it.

Eventually, for the more minor roles, the cost of actually hiring the actor isn’t even the limitation—it’s the cost of finding them in the first place. Putting out ads, running auditions, any negotiating you have to do, and so on, can cost more than the actor you end up hiring will. So Hollywood cuts costs on those as much as they can. “Good enough” carries the day.

A big, established director or producer or what have you *can* push back on the financial bosses—because the big, established director or producer themselves represents a certain amount of protection against risk (they are, presumably, established for a reason, so increased odds that they’ll put together something good, plus their own name can draw crowds even if they mess up in this particular production). That gives them a bit of a “budget,” so to speak, to push for risks. But it’s limited, too. They have to pick their battles. And they’re going to lose some of them. And the less established they are, the less ammunition they’ll have for it.

This is all predicated, of course, on Hollywood’s calculation that these casting choices won’t substantially affect audience draw. Spending money to find an actor with the right accent, or even better, the actor who is actually native to the same area as the character and so can be considered an *expert* on what the right accent is in the first place, doesn’t draw enough of a crowd, in Hollywood’s estimation, to be worth the cost. Or, more accurately, isn’t likely to do so. Spending that money with a low chance of it making you as much money in return is a risk that Hollywood isn’t taking.

The good news here is that audiences are—slowly, gradually—changing to care more about these issues. I don’t know that we’ll ever get to a point where the precise accent of the region in question is going to be seen as a worthwhile choice by Hollywood, but at least we’re seeing push-back on some of the most glaring issues. Blackface was once employed as a way to have a white actor play a black role—that hasn’t been remotely acceptable for a *long* time; for a while now, the only time it was used was ironically, and even that is getting very dim reception these days. White-washing—just changing the minority character into a white character—was seen as an “acceptable improvement” over blackface for a while, but audiences are starting to object pretty heavily to that too. Scarlett Johansson’s casting as Motoko Kusanagi—renamed to just “Major”—in *Ghost in the Shell* raised an uproar, cost that film a lot of money and hurt her reputation—I’m guessing both she and the studio heavily regret her involvement in the film. Tokenism—having a singular example of some minority as pure lip service towards the idea of diversity—is heavily criticized and Hollywood is learning to avoid it.

As these things happen, Hollywood changes its calculations about what is and isn’t risky. If these practices are seen as risky—having a chance of engendering outrage at your film rather than interest—Hollywood will respond to that. Spending more finding the right actor for a role has some risk—all costs represent risks—but if doing it poorly is even more risky, because of the chance that it will turn audiences away from the film, then Hollywood will spend the money.

Comment: It sounds like an opportunity for a staffing agency, honestly. "Same day, correct native accents guaranteed! At deep discounts!"

Comment: I'm sure there would be no need to any discounts. :-)

Answer (score 16):

I live in Hollywood, and have many friends in the business.

Believe it or not this comes up in our conversations quite a bit.

From what I understand, the issues are mainly around casting, and availability of talent. More and more Hollywood  is moving to be more diverse, which is great. Add to that "it's not what you know, it's who you know" definitely plays it's part.

Comment: To summarize: it is not important enough? As a bystander, I felt like every agent has listed the talents of their actors, so if a studio asks for a portugese-speaking clarinet-player, it is not hard to find such...

Comment: Believe it or not, it is hard to find someone in the U.S. who speaks Portuguese (other than Brazilian) that also acts. It is hard to find someone who plays the clarinet (and plays it well) that also acts. To find both those traits in someone who can act well might not be worth the effort in the timeframe given. Especially since an agent’s job and income is based on getting their actor, regardless of the actor’s other talents (language, musical instruments) to the front of any casting line. Though, as a musician, I do understand your point. Some actors can’t fake playing an instrument well.

Comment: Agents are salesmen who sell  to the studios the abilities of their actors to suspend the belief of the audience. But recently, newer studios have instead sought out known, well-established talents, popular in their native countries, to play characters of cultures similar to their own. As long as the actor has a mastery of English for their predominantly English-speaking  main audience. These producers and directors are usually avant-garde, or from new studios like Netflix, Amazon Prime, Hulu, YoutubeTV, etc. That is a step in the right direction, I think.

Comment: I would add to this, the idea of branding. Actor X has made a career portraying "the tough guy" or "the likable guy" and audiences know and love them for it.

Comment: @w.k - I can completely understand your perspective. But, the story, and the emotional impact of the telling of it, are more important factors in its artistic and monetary value. There are many actors who are pilots. There are many actors who are musicians. There are many actors who are athletes. There are many actors who know multiple languages. Their agents listing these talents is not enough to get them a job where the character has those talents.  Tom Hanks & Aaron Eckhart were not pilots when they made “Sully”. But, they did a great job bringing the story to life. Because, they can act.

Answer (score 5):

Upon further reflection, and after reading other answers and comments, it occurred to me there may be an another answer to the question, if one considers the implications of geography.

Could the following be considered the same question,

> "Why does {{ INSERT A LOCAL HERE }} not use foreigners in foreigners' roles?"

If so, I would point out, it's a function of A, geography. B, casting of available/accessible talent. C, target market, and perhaps D, production considerations/dynamics.

My point is, there are certain dynamics at play, what those are exactly I don't know can ever be enumerated, fully.

But I would suggest geography may play a senior role.

And if so, you could say,

> Well marketed, established Hollywood actors, play in Hollywood movies.

Or perhaps the opposite,

> Unknown, not well marketed, Hollywood actors, don't act in Hollywood movies.

Or an extremely, geographical twist,

> Actors from, (insert your local here), who are not known in Hollywood, don't act in Hollywood movies.
> And if framed that way, simplifies the answer considerably.

Now, if you have the question,

> "Is it immoral or ethically wrong for roles to be cast with actors who do not accurately represent the character's ethnicity or accents"

I would suggest, perhaps, that is a great topic for a new question.

Comment: I am almost sure, that Bollywood also does not use foreigners in foreigners roles ;) But it does not concern me, because a) I don't see those flicks b) I don't have too high hopes for them. Like I said in some comment already: mostly, in nowadays European movie/tv making (in my expereience) this topic (native speakers in roles demanding it) is pretty well covered.

Comment: Ok... I think you made my point, Europe is by virtue of geography,  way more representative of numerous ethnicities... And so it goes such their films/TV reflect this.

Comment: @w.k Being an Indian, and having watched hundreds of Bollywood flicks in the seventeen years I have lived yet, I can say that Bollywood almost exclusively uses foreigners(regardless of the country of origin) as goons/henchmen of the bad guy (or as background dancers for songs in some cases). An exception is Nathan Jones who played a villain in the movie [*A Flying Jatt*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Flying_Jatt) but you could say that he was a henchman (possessing superpowers) of the actual bad guy.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar that is an extremely insightful point.

Comment: That reminds me of films which seem to be modeled off of practically the same plot, a villain of (insert ethnicity here) is threatening X hero. At one point in the 80s and 90s it was almost predicable. Which followed the same pattern, I'm actually hard pressed to think of many such films where the villain was an American, in Hollywood films. - perhaps that stems from a notion that people rather not think of themselves as the bad guy... Interesting to hear that it's not too different from the Bollywood films you have seen.

Comment: @AryanSonwatikar Thank you for clarifying and I am really sorry about my ignorance and arrogance towards Bollywood. As far as I understand, Bollywood is the biggest movie industry of the World, but it has (so far) regional influence in India, Pakistan, and South East Asia. Same time Bollywood cares being authentic on the language level. Hollywood has global influence and targets the whole world with its production while does not care about languages besides a few.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding, why did you turn to Moscow with this question. For me, this is not the same question. I can't find on which level it may be the same or similar question. For my observation Hollywood is like the Meka for young actors, Hollywood throws in actors from all over the world as a place who anyone could have a chance to become a movie star. But still, in production, I don't see those people from around the world (playing tiny supporting roles in their native language). My question is all about authenticity, as a watcher, I want to believe, what is going on the screen.

Comment: I meant nothing by it, it  could have been "Africa", "Canada" or whatever local you could think of.

Comment: As Hollywood is unique in this aspect, every other place turns the question some other direction, for me.

Comment: @w.k "Ignorance is bliss" should be applicable to Bollywood as a vast majority of the films it churns out are really bad, and only a few are worth watching. But the thing about Bollywood is that (apart from goons/henchmen or background dancers) the movies rarely *require* foreign actors in important roles; but when they do, it's mostly in a period film set during the British rule. And for that they recruit Englishmen. So superficially it seems that Bollywood cares about language/ethnicity. But in a few films, we've had Pakistani actors playing Indians, which has now stopped. Due to politics.

Answer (score 5):

> It is really annoying to see the roles where “fluent” or “native”
> speaker twists a foreign language. It is embarrassing.

You should consider that maybe most of the target audience probably does not agree with this statement. Since most of the audience does not even know a word of Russian they will probably not notice anything wrong.

Similar example: I am often bothered by butchering of science in movies, but me and people like me probably make a very tiny fraction of target audience, so movie makers do not bother to make us happy.

Comment: ***This*** - there simply isn't much reason to satisfy minor viewer groups, by being very accurate. Unless you underestimate your viewers, that is.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers:

There are factors used in determining whether an actor gets a part other than whether they come from the foreign country.

Remember these people are *actors*, and so their job is to pretend to be someone they're not. For any given character, the casting people must determine which actor is the best fit for the character and can effectively portray that character in the manner that the film/show requires. There are a number of factors in that, their look, their demeanour, their ability to show the emotions felt by the character, to put on their mannerisms and disposition, etc. Not to mention the reputation of the actor themselves which can help with ticket sales.

So if there is an Estonian character, and there are Estonian actors in Hollywood, it doesn't mean that any of those actors are the right fit for this character, and the casters probably don't want to limit their choice of actor to just Estonians, if they can train what they believe to be a better actor (by which I mean better for this particular character / film in their opinion) to do a believable enough Estonian accent that it will not bother the majority of the audience.

Answer (score -2):

Actors union/guild.
Unions is probably your best answer. Even down to the crew who shoots the movie. Just look it up.
You can not just walk around them- they are deep into it. I only know this because my friend works over there and complained about all this (so I was partway listening lol).

Comment: If they want you for a part badly enough, you get a free pass into the right union. Money talks.